# Underlying vs. Overarching

Tags: meaning

In a physical sense, "underlying" and "overarching" have very different definitions, but if we use these words in a more abstract way, their meanings seem to intersect.

For example, is there a difference between the phrases: "the underlying theme in this narrative" and "the overarching theme in this narrative"?

I think there is some nuanced difference here, but I can't quite identify it.

Comment: Why a *nuanced* difference? The difference is broad daylight. An *underlying theme* can never be anywhere near an *overarching theme*. It's not about language or semantics. Can you tell us how you come to be confused?

Comment: I spent a few minutes this morning thinking about how to word this exact phrase in a paper, and came to the conclusion that both would work equally well. Basically, the meaning I want to express is: "the theme that pervades the narrative".

Comment: Now that's another concept: *pervade*. The three words are at the three vertical levels, imagine, all with a lateral spread as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underlying tends to be implicit, because it's underneath--hidden, inaccessible. Overarching tends to be explicit. Everyone can see it. It arches over everything.

Of course, both words also mean "fundamental," so you are right that their meanings intersect.